# Validate Model with Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'd like to validate incoming JSON against a given criteria. For e.g. i have a model class defined as,

```
public class Component 
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

For POST requests, I'd like to ensure that caller does not send Id property value as it will be generated by the service. However, for PUT requests, i'd like to validate that Id property value is specified. I have multiple JSONs that require similar functionality. What is the best method to force model validation in context of controller action? I am using FluentValidation for validating JSON properties but it does not take context (controller action) into account.

Comment: Have you seen this:  https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/434

Comment: So i guess having different models for POST and PUT is the only recommended practice as suggested by Andrei's post below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I look at it, if you don't require the user to send an ID then don't have an ID in your model class.

It is perfectly fine to have multiple models, one for PUT, one for POST. This is good because people know then what properties should be passed through.

So bottom line: only have the properties you need in the model and nothing more, this stops any ambiguity and makes for a far more productive API.

One more thing to consider, PUT don't typically require an ID since one is actually in the URL. If you don't have one in the URL, then you need one in the model.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed.